# Detect and return characters in a Java string

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to write a method that will scan a string for certain characters, and report back which of them (if any) were found:

```
// Special characters are ~, #, @, and *
// If text == "Hello~Clarice, you're s#o ambitious", then this
// method should return a string == "~#". If no special characters
// found, return null. If the same special character occurs 2+ times,
// ignore it and do not return strings with duplicate special chars, like
// "##@***", etc. --> just "#@*".
public String detectAndGetSpecialCharacters(String text) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[~#@*]");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);

    String specialCharactersFound = null;
    if(m.find()) {
        // ???
    }

    return specialCharactersFound;
}
```

I've completed the *detect* portion of this method, but am struggling to find an efficient/elegant way of using the `Matcher` to tell me *which* special characters were found, and furthermore, to concatenate them all together (removing duplicates!) and return them. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a String, you can use a `StringBuilder`, and append each matched character to it, if it is not already there: -

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while (m.find()) {
    String str = m.group();
    if (!builder.toString().contains(str)) {
        builder.append(str);
    }
}

// And finally
return builder.toString();
```

---

Another way would be to maintain a `Set<String>`, and keep on adding matched characters to it. It will automatically remove duplicates. And then you can merge the values of the `Set` to form a `String` using [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) [`StringUtils#join()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.util.Collection,%20char%29) method. Or you can simply iterate over the `Set` and append each string to a `StringBuilder` object. Whatever way you like would fit.

Comment: I think the set is the best way to go. Create a Set, and then use StringUtils to put them all together using StringUtils.join(mySet, "")

Comment: @JonathanC.. Ah! Thanks for that. I was searching for some library Apache or Guava for method like that. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: you are making it complex and inefficient..contains is not required at all if you use the regex correctly

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ.. I would like you to better give some reasoning behind your statement. As you can note, OP don't want duplicate characters if found. And I don't see anything complex here.

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ it is true that this is inefficient for such a simple example where we are only looking for a few characters, however, I am assuming this would be applied to something more complex, in which case, this is an efficient approach. It's true that if we are looking for only 4 characters, this is overengineered.

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ.. And of course, I am not considering just 4 characters, but a wider problem.

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply using `String.indexOf(specialChar)`. Call this method ones for each special char if the result is >= 0 it means that that the special char is present at least one time.

Then order the special chars according the index found to build the resluting String.

Not very elegant, but I think it's efficient because:

- you don't have to remove duplicates.
- if you have many (duplicate) special chars it won't have any impact

Edit (here is sample code)

```
    private static class SpecialChar implements Comparable<SpecialChar>{
        Integer position;
        char c;

        private SpecialChar(char c, Integer position) {
            this.c = c;
            this.position = position;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(SpecialChar another) {
            return position.compareTo(another.position);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String input = args[0];
        char[]  specialsChars = new char[]{'*','@','~','#'};
        List<SpecialChar> results = new ArrayList<SpecialChar>();
        for(char c:specialsChars){
            int position = input.indexOf(c);
            if(position>-1)results.add(new SpecialChar(c,position));
        }
        Collections.sort(results);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(SpecialChar sp:results){
            builder.append(sp.c);
        }
        System.out.print(builder.toString());
   }
```

Comment: I agree with this approach since in this case where we are only looking for a few special chars. If the pattern were any more complex. Something like Rohit Jain's second approach (with a Set) would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You need [capturing-group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg). Just enclose your regex with parentheses and for each `matcher#find` get it. It will be something like:

```
public String detectAndGetSpecialCharacters(String text) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([~#@*])");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
    Set<String> specialCharacters = new HashSet<String>();

    if (m.find()) {
        specialCharacters.add(m.group(1));
    }
    StringBuilder specialCharactersFound = new StringBuilder();

    for (String specialChar : specialCharacters) {
        specialCharactersFound.append(specialChar);
    }
    return specialCharactersFound.toString();
}
```

Adding to `Set` will remove the duplicates and you build your String with special characters at the end. And it will not return null, that normally is not a good thing.

---

**EDIT**

You don't actually need the capturing-group, as your regex is getting only the special characters. You could just use `Matcher#group`. But, it's a good thing to learn one more thing ;)